# How can I generate a "Download URL" with a token using the management API, and is that what I want?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am trying to build a Firebase admin utility that I can use to upload files to Firebase Storage and then return a long lived URL that I can store in the Firebase Realtime DB to access this file.

I believe I can do this in the Firebase Console by going to my project's console, clicking `Storage` on the left, clicking `Upload File`.  Once the file is uploaded, I can get a URL by selecting the file in the list to open the right information pane, and then expanding the `File Location` section.

In that section there is a `Download URL` which appears to be a long lived but revocable URL containing a token of some type.  Is this URL safe to store in a DB for long term storage?  It does appear to be the same URL that is returned from the file [upload api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file), which another Google Codelab (for Flutter) showed being stored in the realtime database.

However, I cannot figure out how to generate that type of URL from the [Firebase Storage Management API](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/File#getSignedUrl).  I am using NodeJS, but it should apply to all versions of the API AFAIK.  I can only find a `getSignedUrl` call which does not seem to return the same URL, and appears to be time limited and containing a link to the service account...not what I want to store in a database.

```
let bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
bucket.upload('innovation3.jpeg', {destination: 'image_assets/innovation3.jpeg'},
  function(err, file) {
    file.getSignedUrl({action: 'read'},
    function(err, url) {
      console.log('Url: ' + url);
    })
  });
```

Is it possible to get this URL from the Management API, or do I need to use some other method.  What is recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signed URLs created with the Firebase Admin SDK (backed by the the Cloud Storage SDK) are different from Download URLs created by the Firebase client SDKs.  They serve the same general purpose, but you can expect them to look different from each other.  They are both safe to store long term, except you should know that Signed URLs have an expiration date, which are you not specifying in your call.  In that case, I don't know what the effective expiration is going to be.

Each invocation of getSignedUrl will generate a new URL.  There is not just one that's unique to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Does anyone know what the result of not setting an expiration date would be?  I am...not particularly comfortable setting an expiration of "+100 years" or something cheesy like that.

Also, the URL generated is in the form:  `https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>.appspot.com/image_assets%2Finnovation3.jpeg?GoogleAccessId=firebase-adminsdk-grsrm@<firebase-project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=NaN&Signature=...`

Since it includes the service account as the access ID seemed not to be something I should store.

Comment: That ID is not a secret.  The secrets are the service account credentials, and your Google account password.